# Vagrant and Chef: How to install a newer version of PHP?

Tags: php, chef-infra, vagrant

I'm relatively new to using [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) and [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/). I'm currently running Ubuntu Lucid 64 and using the [Opscode PHP cookbook](https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/php) which installs PHP 5.3.2, as a package, by default. I'd like to install PHP 5.3.8 or 9 (either from source or as a package) but I can't seem to figure out how to configure it correctly. I have copied over the dependent cookbooks (build-essential, xml, mysql). This is what I have so far:

```
# vagrant_main/recipes/default.rb

require_recipe "apt"

node.override["php"]["version"] = "5.3.9"
require_recipe "php::source"
```

But I am getting an error. Here are the relevant lines of the stack trace:

```
NameError: wrong constant name DebianBeforeSqueeze?
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/recipe_definition_dsl_core.rb:56:in `const_defined?'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/recipe_definition_dsl_core.rb:56:in `method_missing'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/mysql/recipes/client.rb:26:in `from_file'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/cookbook_version.rb:578:in `load_recipe'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:40:in `include_recipe'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `each'
/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/chef-0.10.2/bin/../lib/chef/mixin/language_include_recipe.rb:27:in `include_recipe'
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-1/php/recipes/source.rb:25:in `from_file'
```

**Update:** If I tell the PHP recipe not to worry about MySQL, it seems to install fine...

```
node.override["php"]["version"] = "5.3.9"
node.override["php"]["configure_options"]["mysql"] = false
require_recipe "php::source"
```

...however, Apache doesn't seem to know which version of PHP it's running. `php_info()` is reporting that it's using PHP 5.3.2, but command line (`php -v`) is correctly reporting 5.3.9.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have no experience with Vagrant, but it is entirely possible to have different versions of PHP on your system (the cli variant one version, and either the module of cgi in the webserver another), I reckon that is the case atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load` you can detemine which version of php will Apache use (it has to be installed).

Comment: I haven't looked at this in a long time, but I bet this was the issue. I bet when I installed the Apache PHP module, it was not specifying the correct version of PHP since the CLI version was correct.